# Mount/Unmount ISO and Run a program

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-scripting

I am trying to create a 1-click shortcut to play some old 90s games for an elementary school class.

I am trying to Mount an ISO to a specific drive
Run the program
Make sure the Drive is unmounted for the next game that gets cleared

I am new to scripting so I am not entirely sure where to start. Where I have gotten to is this:

```
@echo off

start N:\Games\ISOs\PoohRTR.iso

start N:\FlynnGames\PoohRTR\PoohRTR.exe
```

This has allowed me to get the game to boot up.. sometimes. I have noticed that the ISO will mount to drive E or F. I need to be able to have it get assigned to E every time. I am assuming I would want to have a command towards the beginning to Unmount drive F to ensure it is open and ready for the next ISO.

I appreciate any input given thank you!

Comment: Experienced readers here filter the stream of Questions that appear based on the provided tags. I have added batch-file and windows as they seem to be the environment you are targeting and will get you more readers for your problem. When adding a tag to your Q, check how many followers are registered. There is no need to use a tag with less that 100 followers (which you did not do, but is often a newbie error). Good luck.

Comment: You could try [a PowerShell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20662684/6738015).

Answer (score 1):

A solution combining with powershell:

```
@echo off
powershell -command dismount-diskimage -imagepath "F:\"
powershell -command mount-diskimage -imagepath "N:\Games\ISOs\PoohRTR.iso"
start N:\FlynnGames\PoohRTR\PoohRTR.exe
goto :eof
```